# Compiler error (invalid conversion from ‘void (*)()’ to ‘__sighandler_t {aka void (*)) in writing signal handler

Tags: c++, linux, process

I wrote a program which reads from a named pipe and after five reads it prints what it read in last five times. I want to write a `SIGTERM Handler` for cleaning up the queue at shutdown. But when I write the handler g++ gave me this error:

> invalid conversion from ‘void (*)()’ to ‘__sighandler_t {aka void (*)(int)}

```
queue<string> q;
void cleanup(){
    while(!q.empty()){
        cout<<q.front()<<endl;
        q.pop();
    }
}
int main(){ 
    signal(SIGTERM, cleanup);
    int fd = open("named-pipe", O_RDONLY, 0);
    char readbuf[80];
    while(1){
        int n=read(fd, &readbuf, sizeof(readbuf));
        readbuf[n]=0;
        q.push(string(readbuf));
        if(q.size()>=5)
            while(!q.empty()){
                cout<<q.front()<<endl;
                q.pop();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your signal handler function must have an appropriate signature. That is take an `int signal_code` argument.

Comment: I read from this link that there is no need of any int.https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node24.html

Comment: @geradism Most of the stuff there (website you linked) are bad examples/usages. I wouldn't use that to learn anything.

Comment: The date on the site says "1/5/1999". A lot has changed since in both C and POSIX standards. So don't use severely outdated references/websites for learning! I'd suggest [TLPI](http://man7.org/tlpi/) book or reading the man pages (they're better references than most websites!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signal handler function's signature is incorrect. It should take an `int` argument.

```
void cleanup(int signal_number){
    ...

}
```

See [signal's](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) documentation.

Your signal handler logic is also suspicious and potentially incorrect. You are not allowed to call async-signal-unsafe functions from a signal handler. Are `cout` and `pop` async-signal-safe?

You main program loops and also calls `pop`. What if a signal arrives in the middle of the `pop` call in main? You'll be calling `pop` again and the queue is potentially in an inconsistent state.